# Move numerically ordered files into corresponding numerically ordered directories

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

I have a directory containing (among various other things), a set of 227 data files with the same extension (.ctl) and numerically listed names (tmp0001.ctl, tmp0002.ctl, tmp0003.ctl... tmp0227.ctl etc.). I'd like to put all theses data files into their own separate directories, named for the data files (i.e. folder1, folder2, folder3... folder227 etc.).

I know how to specify that I want just .ctl files, and to automate the process

```
for file *.ctl
```

But then I have no idea how to make the new directories to move them into in such a numerically ordered fashion.

How should I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If I understood the question correctly, try something like this:

```
for file in *.ctl; do
    if [[ $file =~ 0*([0-9]+)\.ctl$ ]]; then
        mkdir -p -- "folder${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        mv -- "$file" "$_"
    fi  
done
```

`BASH_REMATCH` is a special array where the matches from `[[ ... =~ ... ]]` are assigned to.

Comment: Thanks PesaThe! It seems to have worked perfectly, and you have saved me a lot of time! I haven't seen BASH_REMATCH before.

Comment: The directory might already exist - you'll probably want to use `-p` with `mkdir` (or ignore errors, e.g. with ` || :` after), or execute only if a matching `test -d` fails.  Also, why include the `.ctl` suffix in the match?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use some parameter substitution.

Start with your loop:

```
for file in *.ctl
do

done
```

Within the loop body, we need to turn `$file` into a directory name, by stripping off the suffix and prefix, and leading zeros:

```
dir=${file%.ctl}        # remove suffix
dir=${dir#tmp}          # remove prefix
dir=folder$((10#$dir))  # leading zeros; add new prefix
```

We remove the leading zeros by reinterpreting as a base-ten number (usually numbers beginning with `0` are octal).

Now, it's a simple matter of

```
mkdir -p "$dir"
mv "$file" "$dir"
```